# Same questions migrated multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

Two questions got migrated from Stack Overflow to Programmers and it looks like both somehow got migrated twice:

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84027/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences and [its now deleted pair](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84029/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences). And now there's a third copy of this question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84040/confused-about-the-different-terminology-with-net).
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84031/confused-about-the-different-terminology-with-net and [its pair](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84035/confused-about-the-different-terminology-with-net) which I first merged before deleting for reasons known only to unicorns for they sure don't make sense to me in retrospect.

*ahem*

Anything quirky going on with migrations?

Edit: Looks like the questions weren't actually migrated off of Stack Overflow in the first place. They show up as closed as off-topic and locked by Community. The plot thickens!

Comment: Beat it four right now http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2731/mysterious-question-migrated-5-times

Comment: Now it's up to 7.

Comment: Looking at it...

Comment: in superuser, this question was repeated 14 times: http://superuser.com/questions/297304/rsync-files-newer-than-1-week (15 occurrences)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alas, I'll have to take the blame for this.

A recent [check-in to the MvcMiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/detail?r=f59d4587cd315023478634e914b4f415c00f37f7#) removed serialization support for protobuf-net, and we're profiling migrations... boom.

All should be well, now.